# Path not found in .pro file in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, relative-path, qmake

In my .pro file in Qt project, I have used these two lines for adding necessary LIBS.

```
LIBS          += -L "../../lib/bin/libname.a"  
LIBS          +=  -L "../../rfm2g/winver/libname.lib"  
error: ../../rfm2g/winver/libname.lib: No such file or directory
```

The compiler found the file libname.a, but could not find the libname.lib, although the relative path for both files is correct. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: I posted this as an answer by mistake from the android app. My apologies.  Des your user have reading permissions on thé second file? Does it exist? Is capitalisation correct?

Comment: Are you sure lib and rfm2g are in the same directory ?

Comment: yes they are in the same directory

Answer (score 1):

The `-L` option wants a *directory* for `-l` to search, not the path to the actual library.

So you should either write e.g.

```
LIBS += -L../../lib/bin -lname
LIBS += -L../../rfm2g/winver -lothername
```

***Or*** link with them directly

```
LIBS += ../../lib/libname.a
LIBS += ../../rfm2g/winver/libname.lib
```

---

Also make sure that the paths actually *are* correct. If you change to the build directory, and try to list the files (using `ls` or `dir` depending on platform) using the paths you have, can you list both files?

Comment: @WaleedA Then you have to consider the possibility that the directory or file-name is actually wrong, or you don't have permissions to read the file or one of the directories in the path.

Comment: Pileborgthe path is correct, i m working on windows. and the relative path is starting from the .pro file location. so what do mena by the build directory?

Comment: the first file libname.a  has no problem , and the compiler can read it correctly, but the second file libname.lib has the problem  and can not be found by the compiler

Comment: @WaleedA In this case, the directory where the `.pro` file is located.

Comment: how do you know that the first one is being loaded? Maybe it evaluates them backwards. Try switching the lines

Comment: when i  add the static path e.g.,  LIBS += c:/path/rfm2g/winver/libname.lib then it compiles without prolem, whey with the relative path does  not work